# Error 401 when extracting data from Api from Sonarqube

Tags: python, request, sonarqube

When using the Api address directly in the Browser, it brings the data and Json correctly.

But when trying the same in Postman or Python, the data is not loaded.

The token is valid, I'm on the VPN from the normal company, but without success.

Has anyone been through this and knows a way to analyze it?

**Code**:

```
response = requests.get('https://urlsonar/api/components/search_projects', verify=False)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

**Code 2:**

```
response = requests.get('https://urlsonar/api/components/search_projects', headers={'Authorization': '479ec8bdb82b316abad411fc21d3bed129e19c05'}, verify=False)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

**Error**:

> 401
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Paulo\Documents\projetos\python\CONEXAO_SONAR_EMISSAO.py",
> line 39, in 
> print(response.json())
> File "C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py",
> line 900, in json
> return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 346, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
> PS C:\Users\Paulo\Documents\projetos\python>

Answer (score 3):

The token may be valid, but the way it is used is not. `Authorization` header is supposed to contain authentication method and a value, which in case of method `Basic` should be a base64-encoded string of `username:password`. With SonarQube token you should replace a username with a token and use empty password.

Given the base64-encoded value:

```
$ echo -n '479ec8bdb82b316abad411fc21d3bed129e19c05:' | base64
NDc5ZWM4YmRiODJiMzE2YWJhZDQxMWZjMjFkM2JlZDEyOWUxOWMwNTo=
```

the header should be:

```
Authorization: Basic NDc5ZWM4YmRiODJiMzE2YWJhZDQxMWZjMjFkM2JlZDEyOWUxOWMwNTo=
```

The easiest way, however, with `requests` library would be to use `auth` instead of calculating the header on your own, i.e.:

```
response = requests.get('https://urlsonar/api/components/search_projects', 
                        auth=('479ec8bdb82b316abad411fc21d3bed129e19c05', ''))
```